# Regarding string methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working through Automate the Boring Stuff with Python book and run into curious issue on [chapter 7](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/). 
When trying to execute the following code:

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) != 12:
        return False

    for i in range(0, 3):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False

    if text[3] != "-":
        return False

    for i in range(4, 7):
        if not text(i).isdecimal():
            return False

    if text[7] != "-":
        return False

    for i in range(8, 12):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False

    return True


print("415-555-4242 is a phone number:")
print(isPhoneNumber("415-555-4242"))
print("Moshi moshi is a phone number:")
print(isPhoneNumber("Moshi moshi"))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automation.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(isPhoneNumber("415-555-4242"))
  File "automation.py", line 13, in isPhoneNumber
    if not text(i).isdecimal():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Switching the str.isdecimal() method for str.isdigit() method allows me to execute the code properly, but I would like to know why the isdecimal() method will not work?

Comment: If your book teaches you this sort of Python, then you'd better find another one. The code is very unpythonic.

Comment: As @EliKorvigo says,  this would be an excellent use case for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The regular expression `'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}'` matches your kind of phone numbers.

Comment: `text(i).isdigit()` would raise the same error.  You must have fixed the () typo at the same time.

Comment: @EliKorvigo: Do not blame the book. All CS1-level books in Python follow this approach. Regular expressions are extremely hard to grasp for those who are taking their first programming course.

Comment: @DYZ I'm more concerned about this iteration style.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Ok, then we are on the same page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with `isdecimal()`. You have a typo in how you extract the character from `text`. The

```
if not text(i).isdecimal():
```

should read

```
if not text[i].isdecimal():
```

(note the square brackets.)

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but perhaps, guessing, he thought that this answer should instead have been a comment, coupled with a vote to close as off-topic because just a typo.

Comment: @NPE Thank you! Should have paid more attention for possible typos.

Answer (score 1):

```
  File "automation.py", line 13, in isPhoneNumber
    if not text(i).isdecimal():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The typeError is on line 13, where you are calling a string object. Use `[]` not `()`